# Unable to install node-sass offline - Behind CORP PROXY

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-sass

```
set SASS_BINARY_PATH = C:/darwin-x64-57_binding.node
npm install --global --verbose node-sass

%1 Win32 is not a valid Win32 Application

Tried also this 
 node.exe node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js  --proxy http://uid:pwd@bla install --strict-ssl false
Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:14082174:SSL routines:ssl3_check_cert_and_algorithm:dh key too small:openssl\ssl\s3_clnt.c:3641:
```

Also tried this

```
node.exe --tls-cipher-list="ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:!RC4"      node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js  --proxy http://uid:pwd@bla install --strict-ssl false 

Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:14077410:SSL 
routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake
failure:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:772:
```

Am I missing some setting ?

```
Node v6.11.3
NPM version 5.4.1
NPM PROXY is SET , HTTP-PROXY & HTTPS-PROXY , STRICT SSL set to false
```

*Also its also tries to download https://nodejs.org/download/release/v6.11.3/node-v6.11.3-headers.tar.gz 
SideNote : gives the below error --> dh key too small:openssl\ssl\s3_clnt.c:3641: which impossible to solve in my jurisdiction*

Is there a way I Can skip this installation too and Install it offline ?

Comment: Can this help? => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984308/node-js-openssl-error-dh-key-too-small

Comment: @DavidR in the suggested question - Answer is not possible .. the second Answer is -how can is set the flag when running NPM